# LLMs as "fuzzy JPEGs"

Tags: large-language-models, fuzzy-logic, information-retrieval

We should

> conceptualize LLMs as very quirky and very experimental if advanced
> information retrieval systems (fuzzy JPEGs)

according to **point 7** in the screenshot below ([grabbed from pmarca's Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/pmarca/status/1774547180713631885)).

Could someone please help me understand how "fuzzy" and "JPEGs" are relevant here?

[image]